How to find out what is is preventing my monitors from turning off in Windows 11?
I have set it a 5 min to turn off monitors, but recently something keeps the monitors always on.
I ruled out mice and keyboard.
powercfg /requests yielded no results.
If I force the screens off with a WinAPI call in PowerShell (Add-Type "[DllImport(""user32.dll"")] public static extern int PostMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);" -Name "Win32PostMessage" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru)::PostMessage(0xffff, 0x0112, 0xF170, 2) or an app that does the same like ScreenOff, the monitors will turn off and immediately turn back on.
There is no obvious app that would keep the screen on and I have no clue what else to try to see what's causing it.
I don want my screens on 24/7.
Any suggestions?

Which app are you using to turn the screen off?

@music2myear ScreenOff. You could also do it with a powershell command. But the issue is that some app is waking up the screens.

I'm sorry, that is insufficient information. The details of the app, sufficient to precisely identify it and the version installed on your computer, should be in the body of your question, and you should note Any research you have done regarding this app and how it may not be working also must be in your question. Without this basic information, your question is not answerable and, in fact, lacks evidence of effort on your part to solve it.

Please note that we only know what you tell us. We did not know which "Screen Off" app you were referring to and so did not know what method(s) it used to turn the screen off. Your original question ONLY noted the app as a method of turning off the screen and did not tell us whether you'd checked their documentation or support to see whether they might be aware of an issue.

Now, moving on to other things: Have you updated ALL your system drivers and firmware? Power control issues are often caused by drivers not supporting a given power state. Did your monitors turn off and stay off ok in the past? What happened between them staying off and this present problem starting?

For anyone investigating sleep or monitor off issues, the first step should be running powercfg in an elevated prompt.
Open powershell as an administrator and type:
powercfg /requests

That should give you an overview of could be preventing sleep or screen off states.
Next, you can get a detailed report, again in an elevated prompt, by typing:
powercfg /sleepstudy

This command will generate an HTML report which you can go over and get insights.

The report will have a list of all the state changes.

And clicking on one will take you to the details.
In my case the system was entering the screen off state properly, but being waken by a keyboard input.
I still have to investigate further, but this should be a good start.

Great start to a common problem. Much better to read the beginning of an answer then go back and forth asking for information.
